# How to update object attribute value to null with java.beans.PropertyDescriptor

Tags: java, spring

I need to set the attribute value of the target object to null in case it has the value as empty.

If name is an attribute in target then when name = "", I need this to be changed name=null.

Below is the generic function, how can this be modified.

```java
public String[] justFunc(Object target) {
        final BeanWrapper trg = new BeanWrapperImpl(target);
        for (java.beans.PropertyDescriptor pd : pds) {
        Object srcValue = trg.getPropertyValue(pd.getName());
        if(srcValue instanceof String && ((String) srcValue).isEmpty()){
             //Need value to be set to null when the value is ""
        }
        // Followed by few other checks
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error when you just assign it a null value?  What is the stacktrace?

Comment: pd.setValue(pd.getName(), null), I get nullpointer exception.